# Texture not being shown in rendered animation

Tags: animation, texturing

I decided to do a project using blender to do some rendering and I've followed this tutorial: Blender Tutorial: [Wood Chipping Text Animation](https://youtu.be/YFmN7eTNfNw)

So, everything was going fine, but somehow when I rendered the animation I've made, the textures in the cube and in the text objects wasn't there. Here are prints and my blender file. By the way I am using VLC player to play an OGG file.

Here you have some of the texture details of the one I've used and how I'm using.

[image]

Here I have a frame of my animation beign played in VLC Player, as you see it doesn't show the texture I've used in my project.
[image]

As you guys can see in the images, when I put "rendered" the textures are attached to the objectsm but somehow there are not in the animation.
Does anyone have a clue of why my textures are not being attached to the files in the rendered animation?

Comment: Here you have the blender files https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q7jtpli9akracwb/AABkDeJCpv7v8hiYYSc3mgi0a?dl=0

Comment: Blend file is missing the image texture. Please pack your texture and repost the blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind about posting the new blend file. The reason your texture is not showing up in the render is because you have an override material set in the RenderLayer screen called "Material". It's an empty material which is why the object is rendering as white.

[image]

Comment: No problem! Good luck!